# Bulk import data to ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, elastic-stack

I have elasticsearch data in JSON that i wanna upload at once via curl

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @C:\Users\adm\Desktop\test.json
```

but I get this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_score]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_score]"},"status":400}
```

and the data (test.json) looks like this:

```
{"index" :{"_index":"variationdetails","_type":"_doc","_id":"e17bd50b-fe65-423c-a9f8-4d45ecf56559","_score":1,"_source":{"entityname":"Cislo_f","keyFieldObject":null,"keynotcolumn":false,"keyphrase":"daňový doklad č.","keypositionbottom":301,"keypositionleft":1482,"keypositionright":2000,"keypositiontop":251,"keytovaluedeltaleft":551,"keytovaluedeltatop":7,"userchanged":true,"valuepositionbottom":306,"valuepositionleft":2033,"valuepositionright":2387,"valuepositiontop":258,"variationguid":"a20e3d7a-bf38-4eae-9f23-fb100b539d08","vddid":"e17bd50b-fe65-423c-a9f8-4d45ecf56559"}}}
{"index" :{"_index":"variationdetails","_type":"_doc","_id":"c2a831f1-8156-434c-bd84-08db64c935a5","_score":1,"_source":{"entityname":"Datum_splatnosti","keyFieldObject":null,"keynotcolumn":false,"keyphrase":"Datum splatnosti:","keypositionbottom":1154,"keypositionleft":1706,"keypositionright":2015,"keypositiontop":1112,"keytovaluedeltaleft":421,"keytovaluedeltatop":11,"userchanged":true,"valuepositionbottom":1149,"valuepositionleft":2127,"valuepositionright":2298,"valuepositiontop":1123,"variationguid":"a20e3d7a-bf38-4eae-9f23-fb100b539d08","vddid":"c2a831f1-8156-434c-bd84-08db64c935a5"}}}
```

I tried changing _bulk to variationdetails/_doc but that didnt help.
I cant use elasticdump on the target system (no internet or copy files option)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the bulk insert API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) gives an example and description of the required input.

For each record you want to create or update, you need *two* lines of JSON:

- The first line specifies the *action to take*, and the *document to take it on*. Essentially, the details which would be in the URL and HTTP request method on a single-item action.
- The second line specifies the data to use. Essentially, the details which would be in the *body* of a single-item action.

So for your example, it would look like this:

```
{"index" :{"_index":"variationdetails","_id":"e17bd50b-fe65-423c-a9f8-4d45ecf56559"}}
{"_type":"_doc","_score":1,"_source":{"entityname":"Cislo_f","keyFieldObject":null,"keynotcolumn":false,"keyphrase":"daňový doklad č.","keypositionbottom":301,"keypositionleft":1482,"keypositionright":2000,"keypositiontop":251,"keytovaluedeltaleft":551,"keytovaluedeltatop":7,"userchanged":true,"valuepositionbottom":306,"valuepositionleft":2033,"valuepositionright":2387,"valuepositiontop":258,"variationguid":"a20e3d7a-bf38-4eae-9f23-fb100b539d08","vddid":"e17bd50b-fe65-423c-a9f8-4d45ecf56559"}}
{"index" :{"_index":"variationdetails","_id":"c2a831f1-8156-434c-bd84-08db64c935a5"}}
{"_type":"_doc","_score":1,"_source":{"entityname":"Datum_splatnosti","keyFieldObject":null,"keynotcolumn":false,"keyphrase":"Datum splatnosti:","keypositionbottom":1154,"keypositionleft":1706,"keypositionright":2015,"keypositiontop":1112,"keytovaluedeltaleft":421,"keytovaluedeltatop":11,"userchanged":true,"valuepositionbottom":1149,"valuepositionleft":2127,"valuepositionright":2298,"valuepositiontop":1123,"variationguid":"a20e3d7a-bf38-4eae-9f23-fb100b539d08","vddid":"c2a831f1-8156-434c-bd84-08db64c935a5"}}
```

I'm not sure if `_source` is supposed to be part of the document or not; if not, you probably want this:

```
{"index" :{"_index":"variationdetails","_id":"e17bd50b-fe65-423c-a9f8-4d45ecf56559"}}
{"_type":"_doc","_score":1,"entityname":"Cislo_f","keyFieldObject":null,"keynotcolumn":false,"keyphrase":"daňový doklad č.","keypositionbottom":301,"keypositionleft":1482,"keypositionright":2000,"keypositiontop":251,"keytovaluedeltaleft":551,"keytovaluedeltatop":7,"userchanged":true,"valuepositionbottom":306,"valuepositionleft":2033,"valuepositionright":2387,"valuepositiontop":258,"variationguid":"a20e3d7a-bf38-4eae-9f23-fb100b539d08","vddid":"e17bd50b-fe65-423c-a9f8-4d45ecf56559"}
{"index" :{"_index":"variationdetails","_id":"c2a831f1-8156-434c-bd84-08db64c935a5"}}
{"_type":"_doc","_score":1,"entityname":"Datum_splatnosti","keyFieldObject":null,"keynotcolumn":false,"keyphrase":"Datum splatnosti:","keypositionbottom":1154,"keypositionleft":1706,"keypositionright":2015,"keypositiontop":1112,"keytovaluedeltaleft":421,"keytovaluedeltatop":11,"userchanged":true,"valuepositionbottom":1149,"valuepositionleft":2127,"valuepositionright":2298,"valuepositiontop":1123,"variationguid":"a20e3d7a-bf38-4eae-9f23-fb100b539d08","vddid":"c2a831f1-8156-434c-bd84-08db64c935a5"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer data from cluster to another then best option is to use [Snapshot and Restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html) API of elasticsearch.

If you want to use `_bulk` [API](https://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) then you need to follow bulk api format and your json format should be in below format only. You can create your json file in `ndjson` format for bulk api.

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

```json
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

You are getting error for `_score` because it is internal field / variable of elasticsearch and it show value of relevancy score based on your query.